# Email Block On User Summary Does Not Expand

Tags: contact-summary-editor

The email block on the contact summary does not expand to be edited. I have tested and this is a problem with my install (not repeatable on DMASTER) but I would love some ideas of how to try and solve it.

I can have an email in the block an it looks right.
[image]

If I click edit I get this:
[image]

There are no JS issues shown in the console. I have cleared the cache in the UI and with CV. All the other blocks work as expected.

I have CiviCRM 5.31.1 in Drupal 8.9.10.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: are you saying it is only the email field that mis-behaves? eg do Phone and other fields open as expected?

Comment: Yup, only the email field.  Phone, address, custom fields, etc. all work as expected.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I never added to this.  With no code changes and just a bunch more cache clears this problem fixed itself.

Comment: could you add that as an Answer as SE likes an answer for every question.